# Where is a file placed when it is created like this?

Tags: c, file, stdin, stdio

How can I see where the file is created and open it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char sentence [256];

    printf ("Enter sentence to append: ");
    fgets (sentence,255,stdin);
    pFile = fopen ("mylog.txt","w");
    fputs (sentence,pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file will be created in your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Should find it in the directory you run the app from

Answer (score 0):

The file will be create in the same directory the executable program is in.
you can open the same way you create it, changing the options to the fopen,,

```
FILE *inp;
inp = fopen("FileName","r");
// Do what you want 
fclose(inp);
```

Answer (score 0):

File is created in the same directory as the source code/C File because here you're giving relative path. If you want to put the file somewhere else, you can try giving Full path instead of relative one.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be automatically created in your working directory (where you run the program from).  You can open it in any text editor to make sure it was written properly.

If you meant how do you open it in the code, change `"w"` to `"r"`.